# How do I keep changes in a DBChangeTracker that occur during a sync?

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization, local-storage

I'm using SequelSphere as my HTML5 client database.  I'm also using "change trackers" to track any inserts, updates, and deletes that my app is doing.  When it comes time to sync up the changes, the tracker is reporting the changes perfectly.

Here's the problem:  The sending of the data to the server is asynchronous, and takes some time.  While it is sending the data, I want the app to continue to work, changing more data in tables, and having the change tracker continue to track the changes.  When the sync finishes, I call "tracker.clearChanges()" to remove the changes that were sync'd up to the server.  But a call to "tracker.clearChanges()" will clear all the changes out, including the ones added during synchronization but not yet sync'd up.

How can I call "clearChanges()" and only remove the sync'd changes?  Or how can I keep the changes that the tracker recorded while the sync was occurring?

Thanks,

Bill White

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Question.  I would suggest ending a prior change tracker and beginning a new one such as the following:

```
//  Keeps track of trackers
var curTrackerNbr = 0;
var curTracker = null;
var syncTracker = null;

function getChangeTracker() {
    return db.changeTrackers.create("orders_tracker_" + curTrackerNbr, ["orders_table", "invoice_table"]);
}

function beginSync() {
    //  end current tracking, start new one
    syncTracker = curTracker;
    syncTracker.endTracking();
    //  creating a tracker automatically turns it on...
    curTracker = getChangeTracker();
    //  Get data to be sync'd
    var syncData = syncTracker.getChangedRows();
    //  Perform sync
    syncDataToServer(syncData, onSyncSuccess, onSyncFailure);
}

function onSyncSuccess() {
    //  remove the syncTracker (for cleaning purposes)
    db.changeTrackers.drop(syncTracker.name);
}

function onSyncFailure() {
    if (window.confirm("Want to try again?")) {
        var syncData = syncTracker.getChangedRows();
        syncDataToServer(syncData, onSyncSuccess, onSyncFailure);
    }
}

//  Now, let's create our first change tracker.
curTracker = getChangeTracker();
```

I hope the above code explains it better than my words can!

john...